# Why will xcode code not allow me to drag a slider from my story board to the actual code

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, user-interface, interface-builder

Xcode will allow me to hold down control and drag a UISIlder from my story board and, drag and drop it in the code editor.
Any help would be greatly appreciated I am using xcode 7.2.1 and swift I am also brand new to ios development[image]

Comment: It has nothing whatsoever to do with SpriteKit.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to drag onto a different view controller.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like the view controller in question is managed by a class called "Heat Map". However, you're trying to drag onto a view controller called "ViewController". Try setting your assistant editor to "automatic". When you do that it automatically selects the source file that goes with the storyboard scene you are editing.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `manual` to `automatic`

[image]

and check if the current controller is added in `custom class`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must set your Heat Map scene's view controller (in the Identity inspector) class type to `ViewController` (which, BTW, is a poor name for a custom view controller, since it doesn't convey anything about what kind of view controller it is).

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem as well for no good reason at all. I usually just had to close and reopen split view, or quit Xcode, and then try again. It has always worked after that.